# Canvas Pixel Manipulation Poor Performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, webgl

I am writing a web visualization tool which involves displaying a processed image ~30 times a second.

I have been using the standard canvas tag and using functions such as getImageData/putImageData to perform some pixel manipulation along with drawing circles, squares and paths using beginPath() and bezierCurveTo(), stroke(), etc

Everything is working great but I am getting horrible performance even with hardware acceleration.

Is canvas inherently slow at these types of operations?

I have been researching into using WebGL/THREE.JS for performance, but all I need is to do pixel manipulation with some basic shape drawing. Is WebGL overkill for this? Is there a better alternative?

Ideally I believe I want something that wraps the canvas API but displays it using the WebGLRenderer for performance.

Comment: Note that .getImageData and .putImageData *are not GPU accelerated*.  WebGL has pixel shaders which may speed up your performance depending on how you're manipulating an image.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you are drawing in a Uint8 or Uint32 Array, and then you putImageData this array ? If so, a small webgl program that does just the putImage would be the solution. Did you benchmark what was the cost of your computes vs cost of putImageData ? If putImageData takes the most time, a webgl putImageData (using the array as texture) would give you 60 fps no doubts !

Comment: Some of my drawing is from raw array manipulations along with putImageData(), but some of it is from using beingPath(), fillStyle and bezierCurveTo() etc, are these possible in WebGL? I don't want to drastically make my life difficult by needing to reimplement all the handy drawing functions! :) Edit: I haven't benchmarked things yet, I'll have to check

Comment: Yes, benchmarking would help you to head to the most effective solution. Could you (edit to) describe the pixels manipulation you intend to do ? Because maybe several canvases + playing with globalCompositeOperation could do the job, at a much higher speed than get/putImgData.

Comment: `getImageData` is really slow. Are you calling it? `getImageData` has to freeze everything, wait for the GPU to finish all previous canvas commands, then copy data out of the GPU into memory. Can you avoid calling `getImageData`? `putImageData` is slow but not *that* slow. Here's 2 tests, [one WebGL](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/XLgs6/), [one canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/TVA34/), manipulating pixels in JavaScript. As for `beginPath` and `bezierCurveTo` you'd have to write your own implementations in WebGL. WebGL doesn't provide them.